# Vowel count for each line of txt file

Tags: python, for-loop, count

Trying to count the number of vowels in each line of a text file. So far I have the following;

```
lc=0
lst=[]
vowel_count={}
with open('frankenstein.txt', 'r') as f:
for line in f:
    no_of_characters=len(line)
    l1=line.lower()
    lc+=1
    if no_of_characters !=1:
        for vowel in "aeiou":
            count=l1.count(vowel)
            vowel_count[vowel]=count

            print(lc, vowel_count)

print(lc, vowel_count)
```

I want the output to display the number of vowels and the corresponding line number, which is the purpose of the "lc" variable. 
However when the code runs it gives the following output;

```
2128 {'a': 2, 'e': 6, 'i': 0, 'o': 0, 'u': 1}
2128 {'a': 2, 'e': 6, 'i': 5, 'o': 0, 'u': 1}
2128 {'a': 2, 'e': 6, 'i': 5, 'o': 4, 'u': 1}
2128 {'a': 2, 'e': 6, 'i': 5, 'o': 4, 'u': 3}
2129 {'a': 3, 'e': 6, 'i': 5, 'o': 4, 'u': 3}
2129 {'a': 3, 'e': 6, 'i': 5, 'o': 4, 'u': 3}
2129 {'a': 3, 'e': 6, 'i': 4, 'o': 4, 'u': 3}
2129 {'a': 3, 'e': 6, 'i': 4, 'o': 6, 'u': 3}
2129 {'a': 3, 'e': 6, 'i': 4, 'o': 6, 'u': 2}
2130 {'a': 3, 'e': 6, 'i': 4, 'o': 6, 'u': 2}
2130 {'a': 3, 'e': 5, 'i': 4, 'o': 6, 'u': 2}
2130 {'a': 3, 'e': 5, 'i': 2, 'o': 6, 'u': 2}
2130 {'a': 3, 'e': 5, 'i': 2, 'o': 10, 'u': 2}
2130 {'a': 3, 'e': 5, 'i': 2, 'o': 10, 'u': 3}
2131 {'a': 3, 'e': 5, 'i': 2, 'o': 10, 'u': 3}
2131 {'a': 3, 'e': 8, 'i': 2, 'o': 10, 'u': 3}
2131 {'a': 3, 'e': 8, 'i': 2, 'o': 10, 'u': 3}
2131 {'a': 3, 'e': 8, 'i': 2, 'o': 6, 'u': 3}
2131 {'a': 3, 'e': 8, 'i': 2, 'o': 6, 'u': 3}
2132 {'a': 3, 'e': 8, 'i': 2, 'o': 6, 'u': 3}
```

I get get several outputs for each line, how do i stop this?

Comment: Looks like Python but you should specify what language is that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're printing status after each new found vowel. Move your print out of the inner for loop.